# Order by field in Spinx search with Yii and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, yii, sphinx

Helo, I am new in Sphinx search. I want to get all rows ordered by first_name, but does not happend. Here is my source file:

```
return
"source instructorSourse: _CONNECT_NAME_
{
sql_range_step = 1000
sql_query = SELECT id, first_name, last_name, country_id, city_id,    is_banned, is_deleted, is_confirmed, dive_level as dive_level, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_activity) AS last_activity \
    FROM user AS u \
    WHERE dive_level = 'instructor'  \
    ORDER BY first_name DESC
    sql_attr_bigint = country_id
    sql_attr_bigint = city_id
    sql_attr_bool = is_banned
    sql_attr_bool = is_deleted  
    sql_attr_bool = is_confirmed        
    sql_attr_timestamp = last_activity
   }";
```

But it still return  rows without order. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sql_query` is just getting the data to indexer, it doesnt matter what order you use, indexer will reorder stuff to build the index.

To be able to order the *results* you need to make sure the column is stored in the index - as an attribute. (in your example you could order results by `last_activity` as its an attribute)

So you need to make `last_name` at **attribute**, `sql_attr_string` might be useful, but maybe `sql_field_string` even better, as it makes BOTH a `string` and `attribute`.